# scipy fftconvolve claims input parameters don't have same dimensionality. What am I parsing?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to create a class which uses *fftconvolve* from *scipy.signal* to convolve some data with a gaussian inside a method of the class instance. However every time create an instance and call the method *enlarge_smooth* (which happens upon right arrow key press), I get an error from *fftconvolve* stating: *ValueError: in1 and in2 should have the same dimensionality*. That happens in the function `def fftconvolve(in1, in2, mode="full"):` when the line `elif not in1.ndim == in2.ndim:` evaluates to *True*. However my line `print vals.ndim == gs.ndim` prints *True* before the call to *fftconvolve*, and both *vals* and *gs* have dimensions *(101,)*. So if I am not parsing *vals* and *gs* to *fftconvolve* what am I parsing? And why doesn't it work?

```
class Smoother(object):
    import sys
    sys.path.append("/DATA/Pythonfunktioner")
    from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
    import pyximport; pyximport.install()
    from fitting6 import gs_smooth1
    """
    This class allows the user to smooth any function of one variable with a gaussian using fftconvolve while looking at the smoothed function. The smoothing parameter is changed with the arrow keys and finally chosen with enter.
    """

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.sigma = 1 #smallest possible sigma for this smoothing
        self.arr = np.arange(len(self.data.get_ydata()), dtype='float64') - len(self.data.get_ydata())/2
        self.stack = [data]
        self.line = data
        self.active = True

    def connect(self):
        self.cidkpress = self.data.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.key)

    def key(self, event):
        if event.key == 'right':
            self.enlarge_smooth()
        elif event.key == 'left':
            self.lower_smooth()
        elif event.key == 'enter':
            self.term(event)

    def enlarge_smooth(self):
        if 0: #Check if larger smooth is already in stack
            pass#set larger smooth as current
        else:
            gs = self.gs_smooth1(self.arr.copy(), self.sigma) #Gaussian core centered at 0
            vals = self.data.get_ydata().copy()
            print vals.ndim == gs.ndim
            print vals.ndim, type(vals), vals.dtype
            print gs.ndim, type(gs), gs.dtype
#            print vals, type(vals), vals.dtype
#            print gs, type(gs), gs.dtype
            newsmooth = self.fftconvolve(vals, gs)
            self.line = Line2D(self.data.get_xdata(), newsmooth)
            self.stack.append(self.line)

    def lower_smooth(self):
        if 1: #Check if current smooth is lowest possible
            print "Cannot smooth less. Least smooth already active."
        else:
            pass#Set lesser smooth as current

    def term(self, event):
        self.active = False
        self.disconnect()

    def disconnect(self):
        self.data.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidkpress)
```

I've also tried parsing `vals[0]` and `gs[0]` to check if I would then parse two lists of length 101. It turned out I would really just parse two scalars though, and ftconvolve` would exit with the error: *TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Smoother' and 'float'*.

It looks as though I'm parsing an instance of the class itself. I just can't see how.

If it helps im testing my class trough a call to the following function

```
def smoothBF(datalist):
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    for i in xrange(len(datalist)):
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
        data, = axs.plot(datalist[i][0], datalist[i][1])
        smoother = Smoother(data)
        smoother.connect()
        while smoother.active:
            plt.pause(0.1)
        #Return current result
        plt.close(fig)
```

where *datalist* is a list containing only the tuple `(np.arange(101), np.random.random(101))`

Update: It seems to have something to do with importing fftconvolve inside the class definition. Adding some *print* statements to get the types and number of dimensions inside the scipy fftconvolve function confims that *in1* somehow is a *Smoother* type. But it also gives a different result when I write `from scipy.signal import fftconvolve` in the top of the module istead of inside the class definition and call `newsmooth = fftconvolve(vals, gs)` instead of `newsmooth = self.fftconvolve(vals, gs)`. Then I get the error message *AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'ndims'* from *fftconvolve*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "trick" to import `fftconvolve` inside the class definition trips you up in the end. Unless you haven't shown us where you define `Smooth.fftconvolve` elsewhere.

Here's what you have now:

```
class Smooth(object):
    from scipy.signal import fftconvolve

    def enlarge_smooth(self):
        # other stuff
        self.fftconvolve(vals, gs)
```

And when you call

```
s = S()
s.enlarge_smooth()
```

`fftconvolve` will be called as

```
fftconvolve(self, vals, gs)
```

The solution is simple: don't do this kind of trickery.
Instead, import `fftconvolve` outside the class and just call the function directly:

```
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve

class Smooth(object):

    def enlarge_smooth(self):
        # other stuff
        fftconvolve(vals, gs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow having `from scipy.signal import fftconvolve` inside the class definition makes any call to it parse instances of the class itself. Doing the import outside the class definition and fixing a typo in my edit of *fftconvolve* (as mentioned in the update to my question) makes the parsing correct and the code run.